# how to insert data in mysql table in custom font - font other than english?

Tags: php, mysql, fonts

I want to insert data in mysql table in such a way that it can display data in devanagari font. actually I tried it by using unicode and paste it in table.but is shows error that data is stored like '????????'.
[image]

Comment: use collation `utf8_unicode_ci` to that perticuler field

Comment: http://jonisalonen.com/2012/ultimate-guide-to-utf8-and-mysql/

Comment: thanx Prafulla and n01ze